# Jar discovery with IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

If I have an IntelliJ project (not maven, not gradle, not ant, there is no pom.xml, build.xml...), can I set IntelliJ to find jars in .ivy2, .gradle and .m2 repositories automatically?

Comment: Not that I know of.  If you know where those JARs live, why don't you just add those to your project as libraries and get on with it?

Comment: It works, but it's a hassle. Java has functionality to suggest files to import, it could make a better effort to find more .jars on your machine.

Comment: Hassle?  Ridiculous.  We're talking about adding three libraries to your module.  It takes less time that posting this question did.

Comment: 3 libraries? Did you mean .ivy2, .gradle and .m2? I couldn't make that work. What worked is to find and add the individual .jar inside theose .* repos by hand, hence "hassle". I am very interested if you know how to make IntelliJ understand that .ivy2... is a library. I did try that route, but it continued complaining about not finding log4j, although the log4j was (deep) inside .ivy2. What did I miss?

Comment: Add the directory folders as JAR sources and let the app pull in what it needs.

Comment: Nope. You should try it and see if it works for you. I can see log4j in the project window on the left under external libraries, but JSONObject stays red in the source code, IntelliJ does not find it.

Comment: I'll give it a look tonight and see what I can do, Frank.  Perhaps you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not work from a local directory on the machine, Maven repository is required, however you can install and use a [local Nexus repository](http://www.sonatype.com/Products/Nexus-Professional). Check [this blog post](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/getting-external-libraries-easily/) for more details.

You can also use the [Library Finder](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&pluginId=51) third-party plug-in instead.

Comment: Thanks! How about ivy2 and gradle? Can you do the same thing?

Comment: You can try the Ivy plug-in: http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&pluginId=3612, also updated the answer with a link to Library Finder plug-in.